# How to create a single project out of multiple docker images

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have been working on a project where I have had several docker containers:

- Three OSRM routing servers
- Nominatim server
- Container where the webpage code is with all the needed dependencies

So, now I want to prepare a version that a user could download and run. What is the best practice to do such a thing?

Firstly, I thought maybe to join everything into one container, but I have read that it is not recommended to have several processes in one place. Secondly, I thought about wrapping up everything into a VM, but that is not really a "program" that a user can launch. And my third idea was to maybe, write a script, that would download each container from Docker Hub separately and launch the webpage. But, I am not sure if that is best practice, or maybe there are some better ideas.

Comment: Depending on what your solution does, you might consider turning it into a SaaS offering where you host it and give the users access. Asking a user to run (and maybe troubleshoot) a setup with multiple containers is not something I'd want to do.

Answer (score 2):

When you need to deploy a full project `composed` of several containers.
You may use a specialized tool.

A well known for mono-server usage is `docker-compose`:

> Compose is a tool for defining and running multi-container Docker applications
> https://docs.docker.com/compose/

You could provide to your users :

- docker-compose file
- your application docker images (ex: through `docker hub`).

Regarding clusters/cloud, we talk more about `orchestrator` like `docker swarm`, `Kubernetes`, `nomad`

Kubernetes's documentation is the following:
https://kubernetes.io/